# CGI File Writing File w/only Read Permissions

Tags: javascript, json, permissions, apache2

My web server sends a xmlhttprequest to write a JSON file whenever a button is clicked. However, the file has only read permissions when written. Also, this ONLY happens when the web server asks the cgi script to execute. However, if I try executing this cgi script myself from command line, the file is written with both read and write permissions. Is there any way I can allow the web server to make this cgi script write a file with full permissions?

As requested, here is the part of my code which sends the xmlhttprequest and fetches/the json file.

```
<script>
        function loadXMLdoc() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "/cgi-bin/run.cgi"
            var id = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
            var mutation = document.getElementById("inputMutation").value;
            var position = document.getElementById("inputPosition").value;
            var json;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

                    $.getJSON("data.json",function(result){
                        $.each(result, function(i, field){
                            output = "<h1>Output<h1>"
                            for (var f in field){
                                output+="<p>Identifier: " + field[f]["value"]+" Position: "+field[f]["position"]+" Mutation: "+field[f]["mutation"]+"</p>"
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    document.getElementById("test_container").innerHTML = output    
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url+"?id=" + id + "&mutation=" + mutation + "&position=" + position, true);
            xmlhttp.send()
        }
    </script>
```

And here's the part in run.cgi which writes the file.

```
write_file = open("%s/data.json" %(root_directory), 'w')
write_file.write('{"results": [\n')
for i,result in enumerate(results):
    write_file.write('\t{"value": "%s", "mutation": "%s", "position": "%s"}' %      (result["value"], result["mutation"], result["position"]))
    if i != len(results) - 1:
        write_file.write(",")
    write_file.write("\n")
write_file.write("]}")
write_file.close()
```

Comment: `chmod 0777 cgiscript` will set read/write/execute permission for everyone.

Comment: Hmm, yes I know about the chmod command. However, this JSON file is constantly rewritten, which would mean I have to chmod it everytime. I chmod 777'd it once, but when the cgi script was executed again, it created a new, locked permissions file again.

Comment: @JonathanM I just added the code which sends the request and opens the JSON file

Comment: @JonathanM and the part in run.cgi that opens the file for writing.

Comment: You don't need to do `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();` *and* `$.getJSON()`. Just do `$.getJSON` and don't create an xmlhttprequest object. The `$.getJSON` will create it for your. As it is now, you're doubling up on objects.

Comment: @JonathanM hmm, the XMLHTTpRequest() is for executing run.cgi though. run.cgi basically does mysql parsing and other computation to output a result, which it writes to data.json, and only when data.json is ready should the program read it

Comment: Why are you writing the JSON to a file instead of just returning it immediately?

Comment: @JonathanM Some of the methods used to get the final result is run.cgi have built-in print statements, which I did not want to be outputted, so I instead just wrote only the result to a JSON. I suppose I could just return it immediately though and parse out those unwanted print statements.

Comment: It would be best, if possible, to change the methods to not write to stdout (bad practice). If not possible, you might precede the call to those methods with code that outputs the opening of the JSON, `{ "discard" : "` and then after the methods print `",`. Then build the rest of the JSON and return it. The client won't have to parse it, because the junk will be in the `discard` property.